# grounding in off-grid installations

Tags: electrical, grounding-and-bonding

I will spend some weeks completely off-grid with a AC inverter generator, a battery charger, a 12V battery and a small inverter. Why a generator and an the inverter? because I'll use the generator only to charge the battery through the charger.. and use the battery as the source of power thought the inverter. I've read that there should be only 1 bonding of neutral and ground in a system in order to trip the breaker in a case of short

I made a diagram of the installation I imagined.
[image]
I'm not using a ground rod as I read it isn't required. Please tell me if you see anything wrong.

Comment: what are spd and rcd?

Comment: "I'm not using a ground rod as I read it isn't required. Please tell me if you see anything wrong." - um, the previous sentence.

Comment: @MadMonty, Residual Current Device and Surge Protection Device.  Thats what they are in NZ anyway.  The RCD measures the mismatch between Line and Neutral and opens the circuit if they are a few mA off.  The assumption being that it leaking to Ground or to something else.

Comment: Have you considered the interaction between AC and DC grounding in this system?  I take it your charger and inverter are both isolating types?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I'll check the specs.. I assume the charger and inverter are isolated from ground. What could change if isn't the case?

Comment: @jmann -- your electrical regulations may call for grounding of the DC system

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel the manufacturers tell me the charger and the inverter have AC and DC isolated from each other. Anyway 12V is too low to consider any protections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add GFCI off the generator, another off the breaker box to feed the appliances, and a ground rod.  The ground rod (along with all the equipment ground conductors) insures that the exposed metal parts of everything associated with the wiring is at ground potential, even if something goes sideways.  Since you're presumably working outdoors in weather, you don't want to risk grabbing onto something live that you can't let go of.  I've done that with an unprotected circuit.
The single point ground-neutral does not affect overload tripping, but it can interfere with GFCI operation by making it trip when it shouldn't.

Comment: Thank you @MadMonty, I'll add the grounding rod then ;) RCD and GFCI are the same ;) The N-G bonding close the circuit so the RCD/GFCI breaker can trip in a case of a fault.. what I read is that it has to be done only in one place of the system

Comment: Ah, now that I understand RCD=GFCI, I agree you need only one.   I grounded my generator and replaced its AC receptacles with GFCI's, since it is not hardwired and there is no assurance that cords and devices downstream will have their own protection.  If you use the generator for other things besides this system, you might want to do the same.  (Regarding number of ground rods, here in US, multiple ground rods may be required where soil conductivity is poor, but they all connect to the same G-N bond point - which I take to be your point and with which I agree.)

Comment: thanks. I'll connect everything after the RCD/GFCI just to keep the generator as it is. For the same reason I'll do the G-N bond outside of the generator

Answer (score 1):

In your system 1 drawing, I'm not sure why you need a breaker box off the generator, since generators are intrinsically self-limiting sources (a 3 horsepower engine isn't going to make more than 2237.1 watts no matter what you do to it).  And most small ones of "appropriate for battery charging" size already include onboard RCD (30mA threshold, or even human-safety-rated 6mA threshold). So I would consider going straight from generator to battery charger.

In your system 2 drawing, you seem to show neutral-ground bonding in the "breaker box" with a very lightly drawn line...  and that's where it belongs. You should really bond it to the earth with a rod.  Also, even if the system 1 is isolated, its grounds should still be tied into this.

Comment: @Monica thanks for the response. The idea of the box breaker is to have a RCD/GFCI breaker and the single N-G bonding for the system.. the SPD isn't required since the generator will not make any surge, but I put it just in case. Didn't know the generator come with a RCD, but I'll use the same breaker box for both systems ;) As people have tell me, I'll add a ground rod to the systems ;)